# Mail server still BLACKLISTED after fix the issue

Tags: exchange, smtp, blacklist

I have an Exchange 2007. CBL has blacklisted me because:

> This IP address is HELO'ing as "localhost.localdomain". If you test
>   and helos properly means something OTHER than your mail server
>   software is making the connections.

I've tested with **7** different online tools for my HELO FQDN and all of them says its ok, please see screenshot (let's say FQDN is **correo.xxxxxx.es**)

[image: http://oi61.tinypic.com/15heq8i.jpg]

Every single test says my FQDN is OK and isn't localhost.localdomain.
I've asked CBL to remove me but they block me again for the same reason :( :( :(

Here's what I've done so far:

1- MX records are pointing to "correo.xxxxxx.es"

2- "correo.xxxxxx.es" is pointing to my IP

3- PTR record is resolving to "correo.xxxxxx.es"

4- SPF Record configured

5- DKIM certificate configured

5- On Exchange, Send and Receive connector configured to correo.xxxxxx.es

6- 25,110,143 y 587 ports forwarded to Exchange server

6- I have a DavMail server that connects Linux and mobile clients but it uses 1025 and 1143

7- I have blocked ALL outgoing traffic on port 25 on my Firewall except for Exchange server, avoiding the DavMail or anything to answer any SMTP HELO.

What else can I do?

Comment: Can you try from another machine to connect to port 25 using telnet? You could try then "HELO localhost" and see what is the answer, just because it looks like all the tests are trying with EHLO, maybe the behaviour of the Exchange server is different between HELO and EHLO

Comment: Here is a screenshot with the answer:

http://oi58.tinypic.com/x38imb.jpg

Comment: It looks like CBL is caching the answer or giving you the wrong reason. Is the mailserver behind a NAT? It looks like they are very aggressive against NAT ( http://cbl.abuseat.org/nat.html )

I'm afraid the only thing you can do at this moment is go through the FAQ and contact them once you've checked all the points.